# create a class which do some animation and show it on screen

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to create a new class that has many sprites on it , and they perform some actions one after another, and do some other cool stuff on screen.

this whole "show" will be in some class,that appears on screen when i need it .

On my main class `Main` which is a `CCScene`, i want to have the ability , to just call that animation class whenever i want to , and that it will be added to my main screen and perform its "show" .

```
some class :
 //FADE ACTIONS
    fadeInAction=[CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:0.5];
    fadeOutAction=[CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:0.5];
    fadeOutFastAction=[CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:0.1];


    //circle animation parts
    for (int i=0;i<12;i++)
    {
        circlePartsArray[i]=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"c%d.png",i+1]];
        circlePartsArray[i].position=ccp(winSize.width/2,winSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:circlePartsArray[i]];

    }
```

Then from my main class i want to see on my screen, all the performance that `someClass` do- the sprites added, than they will fade etc..

How would i define that class, and add it to my main scene ?

Answer (score 0):

Extend the CCNode class. Overwrite the CCNode Class' onEnter method, which you will use to create and add the child sprites, and start the animation. This way whenever you add the Node to your scene, it will begin the animation (probably using action sequences). Your animation action sequences should end with a CCCallBlock action, which you will use to clean up and remove the Node from its parent.

Comment: i have tried to create another cclayer and add it but i dont see it on screen. check it :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588172/return-a-class-as-a-layer

Comment: @user1994291 I don't know Java.