# return a class as a layer

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

This question is using `cocos2d with xcode`, but i think general objective c guys can handle it.

I have a class which is a `CCLayer` and i want to return it as a layer to my main class and show it in there(and all actions happens in that layer class) .

so the "other" class is :

```
CCSprite *r;


    -(id)set
    {
        r=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"c5.png"];
        r.position=ccp(50,50);
        [self addChild:r z:3];
        return self;


    }
```

and from main class i call it with :

```
recieverCircleLayer *r=[recieverCircleLayer alloc] ;
        [self addChild:[r  set ]];
```

so nothing is happen and i dont see that sprite from the other class on screen.

what am i missing ?
thanks .

Comment: Instead of `(id)`, can you try `(instancetype)`?

Comment: i have tried -(CCLayer*)set; which is the type. i still dont see anything..

Comment: What is the type of the main class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second code snippet should be:

```
recieverCircleLayer *r = [[recieverCircleLayer alloc] init];
[self addChild:[r  set]];
```

You forgot the `init` in `alloc-init`. Regardless of whether or not that completely solves your problem, it's definitely a step in the right direction. ;)

Also, class names should start with an uppercase letter and be camel cased all the way through. For example, `RecieverCircleLayer`.

Comment: thanks a lot for advices. but the init is to initialize the variables and has nothing to do with the fact that its not working, but thanks a lot .

Comment: @user1994291 You should always send `init`, regardless of whether or not your subclass initializes state within the actual initialization method.

Comment: no way ! it worked with the init ! why is that ? init is not the way to initialize all instance variables ? why it has to do something with my class that dont have instance variables ?

Comment: @user1994291 The way `init` works is that it goes up the superclass chain. When your implementation of your initializer is called, it calls it's super classes' initializes in a chain to `NSObject`/`NSProxy` so that they can do their initializations. A subclass inherits from its superclass and, thus, must let its superclass perform its initializations too. If I have a `Vehicle` class that has a whole bunch of state that it initializes with `init`, a `Car` subclass would need the same initialization as its superclass, usually followed by its own specific to its purpose.